# How long does it take for a dead body to disappear?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I accidentally killed a load of people. I didn't have enough cash to revive them all, and was forced to leave a few of the corpses around the place. However, after a while, the corpses disappeared entirely, and I couldn't revive them!

How long does it take for corpses to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly remove them, they will disappear in 24 hours, whether you have the game open or not (24 real hours, not game hours.) That can give you time to earn caps to revive them if you desire.